# @media only screen and (orientation:portrait){} not working in iOS Emulator?

Tags: css, mobile-safari, ios-4.2

`@media only screen and (orientation:portrait){}` not working in iOS Emulator? Any solution to make it work?

I'm using iOS emulator for ipad. and Emulator is in Portrait mode

But it's not taking whatever is written inside

```
@media only screen and (orientation:portrait){



}
```

[image]

**Edit:** I just tested with this link too http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/media-queries/ I think Simulator doesn't detect Media queries.

**Edit 2:** I also uploaded video here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1R_QEfRD9xc&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I tested in the simulator and it works just fine: http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Test/MediaQueries/20100726/media-queries-test.html

Answer (score 0):

Open project with safari and enable a "Show Develop menu in menu bar".
Open menu on Develop and select User Agent > iPad

Resize Window and `@media only screen and (orientation:portrait){}` now work

Comment: But I'm asking about Simulator